# How to control visibility of the deleteAddress tab per user

Tags: activemq-artemis

In `management.xml` this filter does not work:

```xml
<match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="address=myadress1">
   <access method="delete*" roles="myrole1"/>
```

**Scenario:**

When the user clicks on `myadress` in console tree => the tab `deleteAddress` shows. For other addresses not.

**Outcome:**

The `deleteAddress` tab does not show.

I have read Artemis and JBoss documentation.

Comment: Yes, if there's no bindings.

Comment: @JustinBertram In context of existing bindings, myrole1 must do purge and delete queue first. That is taken care of. I realize that i need to rephrase the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of the "Delete Address" tab is not an indication of whether or not the user can actually delete the address in question. All tabs are displayed regardless of security permission because the web console itself has no knowledge about authorization details. Security is enforced *on the broker* when the operation (e.g. delete address) is executed. If the user is not authorized for that operation then they will receive an error when that operation is executed.

Comment: Using method="deleteAddress" actually controls the visibility of the tab. Tested with different role and it disappered.